# Can't create dynamic table from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How I can create dynamic table with JQuery from these object

Object is array type and store every column data.

I want table like this:

`+--Start_Hour--Start_Minutes--Start_Month--+
| 11          | 00           | 07         --|
| 03          | 03           | 03         --|`

[image]

Yes, but its bad code :(

```
function GenerateHolidayTable(data) {
  var name, number;
  var HolidayTableHTML = '';
  HolidayTableHTML += '<table class="table"><tr><th>Start_Month</th><th>Start_Day</th><th>Start_Hour</th><th>Start_Min</th><th>End_Month</th><th>End_Day</th><th>End_Hour</th><th>End_Min</th> <th>Description</th></tr>';
  $.each(data, function(key, value) {
    if (key == "Start_Month") {
      HolidayTableHTML += '<tr>';
      $.each(value, function(key, value) {
        HolidayTableHTML += '<td>' + value + ' </td>';
      });
    }
    ..................................
    else if (key == "Description") {
      $.each(value, function(key, value) {
        HolidayTableHTML += '<td>' + value + ' </td>';
      });
      HolidayTableHTML += '</tr>';
    }
  });
  HolidayTableHTML += '</table>';
  $('#HolidayTable').append(HolidayTableHTML);
}
```

Comment: have you try to code something  ?

Comment: That's more than just bad code. If I suppose that `$('#HolidayTable')` is a `<table>`, then you just add another table in it.

Comment: Fine then. Check out the answer of @anu. It'll set you on the right track.

Comment: What is wrong with your code exactly?

Comment: All element generate in one row. I don't know how make new row from that data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

*Assuming all the three (Start_Month,Start_Hour & Start_Minutes) will have equal length.*

```js
var json = "{\"Start_Month\": {\"1\" :\"1\",\"2\" :\"2\",\"3\" :\"3\"},\"Start_Minutes\": {\"1\" :\"10\",\"2\" :\"20\",\"3\" :\"30\"},\"Start_Hour\": {\"1\" :\"01\",\"2\" :\"02\",\"3\" :\"03\"}}";
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(json);
$.each(jsonObj.Start_Hour, function(idx, val) {
  var row = "<tr>";
  row += "<td>" + val + "</td>";
  row += "<td>" + jsonObj.Start_Minutes[idx] + "</td>";
  row += "<td>" + jsonObj.Start_Month[idx] + "</td>";
  row += "</tr>";
  $("#data").append(row);
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table,
td,
th {
  border: 2px lightblue solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Start_Hour</th>
      <th>Start_Minutes</th>
      <th>Start_Month</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="data"></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hmm makes sense. I missed the json structure that `Start_Hour` etc are individual arrays.+1

Answer (score -2):

Have you looked into a javascript templating system such as [Mustache JS](https://mustache.github.io/)?

As it would make something like that relatively easy to do.